# Flutter API registration with Laravel throwing 'Connection reset by peer' error; how to resolve?

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer

void registerUser() async {

```
final data = {
  'email': email.text.toString(),
  'username': name.text.toString(),
  'password': password.text.toString(),
};


final result = await Api().postRequest(route: '/register', data: data);
final response = jsonDecode(result.body);
if (response['status'] == 200) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Login(),
    ),
  );
}
```

}